# How do we decide on number of convolutional layers in our Convolutional Autoencoder?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying to build a convolutional autoencoder for laser scan data, but I am not able to know the number of convolutional layers that are needed for it?

The input will be 1D and we are trying to reconstruct the data using the autoencoder.

Answer (score 0):

When constructing auto-encoders, you expect the loss between the reconstructed data and the original to be low. If it is possible to understand the error in output data by checking the value of the loss (for example mean square loss), then you can stop adding new layers. If the value of loss does not make sense, then you can reconstruct the input data and compare them visually.